# Module is not found in the Catalog

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

I have 2 modules that I am trying to access from the app config file.

[image]

The image is the project properties for ModuleA.

The solution name is SampleApp

The Project is ModuleA and the Class is ModuleA (The same for ModuleB)

The config looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="modules" type="Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Prism.Wpf" />
  </configSections>
  <modules>
    <module assemblyFile="ModuleA.ModuleA.dll" moduleType="ModuleA.ModuleA, ModuleA.ModuleA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="ModuleA" startupLoaded="false" />   
    <module assemblyFile="ModuleB.ModuleB.dll" moduleType="ModuleB.ModuleB, ModuleB.ModuleB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="ModuleB" startupLoaded="false">
      <dependencies>
        <dependency moduleName="ModuleA"/>
      </dependencies>
    </module>
  </modules>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I am setting the congif file as a resource, but when i compile, I get the error

Module ModuleA was not found in the catalog.

Is my config correct?

Comment: Is ModuleA's assembly file actually called `ModuleA.ModuleA.dll` or is it just `ModuleA.dll` ?

Comment: No its just ModuleA.dll.     I was just trying ProjectName.Name.dll to see if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

First off,  would recommend naming your Module classes different from the project to help eliminate confusion.  Something like ModuleAModule.cs

Your config should look like this:

```
<module assemblyFile="Assembly.dll" moduleType="Assembly.ModuleName, Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" moduleName="ModuleName" startupLoaded="true"/>
```

You also need to make sure that you are copying the Module assembly into the executing directory.  So make sure you have an xcopy in the Module post build event to copy the assembly to the proper location.